# Variable horizontal sizing with generated divs

Tags: html, css

Need help with formatting this properly... 
So this webpage/application generates a small set of boxes that serves as a basic graph for trending resource usage.

The gHolder and graphContainer are fixed, and the graphBar classes are generated one per second up to a fixed number of bars (I only included a few for brevity) 
At the end of that there should be an overall percentage in a box (Also generated in Javascript)

Currently I can make this work if I have a fixed number of graphBar entries that are less then the smallest screen resolution I expect.

Id like to make this dynamically size... but unfortunately, when I try and make the container equal the size of the available area... It either leaves a great big empty area... or If I have more graphBar entries then it can display it wraps them rather than hiding the overflow.

I currently have it using the CSS Table functions which is I assume the problem... but I cannot seem to make this work any other way.

Image of the general shape:

[image: CPU Graph]

Basic HTML structure:

```
<div class="gHolder">
  <div class="graphContainer" id="CPUHistoryGraph">
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="graphSingle" id="status_miniCPUgraph" style="width: 5px;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a jfiddle of the problem. PLease play with it and see if you can come up with a good way of doing things:

https://jsfiddle.net/84recnzg/

Comment: Are you adamant about using stylized divs for this? Seems like <canvas>, or some of the manyJS graphing libraries would be much more apt for this task.

Comment: Not adamant. But since I am modifying an exisiting page... I feel like the simplest would be just to figure out how to make these CSS/Html changes.
If you have a link to a superior system, I am always happy to learn.

Comment: d3 might be want you want then. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt really fix what I have here. Like I said, Id rather not make any huge modifications quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this just by changing the CSS styles from the JSFiddle that you provided. For example, some of the changes would be:

- Adding some `position`: `relative` for the parent, and `absolute` for the boxes inside.
- Setting a really large width for `.graphContainer`.
- Setting the `overflow` to `hidden` for the parent.

```css
.gHolder {
    height: 102px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.graphContainer {
    width: 100000px;
    height:0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

.graphInfo {
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 102px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 0px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.graphBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gHolder">
  <div class="graphContainer" id="CPUHistoryGraph">
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:8px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:16px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:2px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:9px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:15px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="graphInfo">
    <div class="graphSingle" id="status_miniCPUgraph" style="width: 5px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this example on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84recnzg/2/, and you would still need to play with the rest of the styles to make them fit (e.g.: the text in the `.graphInfo` box).

---

But setting up a really large `width` has a problem: if you let it run sufficient time, the number of graph bars will be enough to overflow and you'll have the issue of the two lines.

One quick solution for that would be to set the `width` dynamically using JavaScript each time that you add a graph bar (width = number of bars * space of bar, where space of bar would be the width of the bar + its separation with the next bar).

Something like this (I used 11px for each bar):

```
document.getElementById("CPUHistoryGraph").style.width = (document.querySelectorAll(".graphBar").length * 11) + "px";
```

That you can see in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84recnzg/3/

---

To fix the issue mentioned in the comments below:

- Add a `display:table` and specify a width for the graph holder box
- Remove the `height` and `width` for the graph container

```js
function addBar() {
    
    // add a new bar with a random height
    aux = document.createElement("div");
    aux.className = "graphBar percent_low";
    aux.style.marginLeft = "4px";
    aux.style.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*99 + 1) + "px";
    document.getElementById("CPUHistoryGraph").appendChild(aux);
  
    // recalculate width for the graph area 
    document.getElementById("CPUHistoryGraph").style.width = (document.querySelectorAll(".graphBar").length * 12) + "px";
}

// recalculate width for the graph area
document.getElementById("CPUHistoryGraph").style.width = (document.querySelectorAll(".graphBar").length * 12) + "px";
```

```css
.gHolder {
    height: 102px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;  
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.graphContainer {
    /*width:100000px;
    height:102;*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

.graphInfo {
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 102px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 0px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.graphBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gHolder">
  <div class="graphContainer" id="CPUHistoryGraph">
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:8px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:16px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:2px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:9px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:15px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:7px;"></div>
    <div class="graphBar percent_low" style="height:5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="graphInfo">
    <div class="graphSingle" id="status_miniCPUgraph" style="width: 5px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addBar();">Add bar</button>
```

You can also see it on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84recnzg/9/

For some reason, in the JSFiddle all the bars are displayed aligned to the bottom, but on the demo above some seem to be 1px off (not all, just some). It's a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. Although you might have confused the Jsfiddle links, you posted the same one twice.

Comment: I just fixed that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Still having a problem. The bars float to the top of the container. Unfortunately, as is the case in alot of instances, I cant put the whole website up here for you to poke through, Can you think of anything that might make those go up?

Comment: I added an edit: changed the CSS a little and added a button to see how it would behave with different bar sizes